# How to get order records whose user id already made more than 1 orders

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to count order records with users who made more than one order in a month like 2018-01-01 to 2018-02-01.

```
Order table
id   user_id   date
1    12        2017-01-02  <- first order(no count)
2    23        2018-01-03  <- second order(count)
3    12        2018-01-04  <- second order(count)
4    12        2018-01-08  <- third order(count)
5    23        2017-11-02  <- first order(no count)
6    11        2018-01-01  <- first order(no count)
....

User table
id
11
12
23
....
```

## Output

```
 date     count(*)
 2018-01-01     3
```

I think I need to get order records first and find order records again with certain user_id. But I'm stuck
Is there a way to accomplish this task?
Thanks

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I need to count the result. It&#39; not duplicate question

Comment: Your counting is not correct.. `5    23        2017-11-02  <- first order(no count)`  is outside the date filter ( 2018-01-01 to 2018-02-01).. so `2    23        2018-01-03  <- second order(count)` is technical the first record which not should be counted.so the output should be two..

Comment: @Barmar sure i know that stackoverflow is not a consultant. I didn't post query here because i tried it at work and left. I will update this post tomorrow. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select count(*) from 
(select user_id, count(*)
from `Order`
where date >= '2018-01-01' and date < '2018-02-01'
group by user_id
having count(*) > 1) users_w_multiple_orders;
```

The `having` command is how you filter results from an aggregation like `sum`. After you have that, you can count the results from that query.

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word